# AngularJS reload directive template

Tags: twitter, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an AngularJS directive to show twitter share button, after every attribute change i need to reload and compile directive template because after calling twttr.widgets.load the contents will be replaced with an iframe contains the button.

```
function TwitterShareDirective($twitterRender, debounce, $compile) {
        function template() {
            var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.href = 'https://twitter.com/share';
            element.setAttribute('class', 'twitter-share-button');
            element.setAttribute('data-url', '{{href}}');
            element.setAttribute('data-text', '{{text}}');
            element.setAttribute('data-via', '{{via}}');
            element.setAttribute('data-size', '{{size}}');
            element.setAttribute('data-related', '{{related}}');
            element.setAttribute('data-hashtags', '{{hashtags}}');
            element.setAttribute('data-lang', '{{lang}}');
            return element;
        }
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: template(),
            scope: {
                'href': '@url',
                'size': '@size',
                'text': '@text',
                'via': '@via',
                'related': '@related',
                'hashtags': '@hashtags',
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                scope.lang = $twitterRender.getLang();
                var render = function () {
                    var dom = template();
                    element.empty();
                    element.append(dom);
                    $compile(dom)(scope);
                    scope.$apply();
                    $twitterRender.render(element[0]);
                };
                var debouncedRender = debounce(render, 800);
                attr.$observe('url', function () { debouncedRender(); });
                attr.$observe('size', function () { debouncedRender(); });
                attr.$observe('text', function () { debouncedRender(); });
                attr.$observe('via', function () { debouncedRender(); });
                attr.$observe('related', function () { debouncedRender(); });
                attr.$observe('hashtags', function () { debouncedRender(); });
            }
        };
    }
```

EDIT: Problem solved

I fixed the problem using the solution from @irth and scope.$apply() that make the magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in your render function:

```
var domElement = document.createElement(newVal);
element.empty();
element.append(domElement);
$compile(domElement)(scope);
```

If that doesn't do the trick out of the box, please see how I did it here: https://github.com/irthos/ecopos4/blob/master/app/directives/helper.js

Comment: I try your solution but it will render a twitter button with an html that is not compiled (but the output of $compile returned function return a compiled html with my scope)

Answer (score 1):

In your render function call the $compile as follows:

```
var render = function () {
              //Here I want to replace contents with new compiled template;
              $compile(element)(scope);
              twttr.widgets.load(element[0]);
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it into a `ng-if` directive.

```
<div ng-if="doRender">
  <!-- content -->
</div>

// In directive whenever you need a reload

$scope.doRender = false;

// Postpone to end of digest queue

$timeout(function() {
  $scope.doRender = true;
});
```

Comment: adding $timeout doesn't work, unless I do add some time to $timeout. Like this - `$timeout(function() {
  $scope.doRender = true;
},500);`   Is there any way to avoid time addition to $timeout.